# How to pass git pathspec args using node spawn

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

I am trying to run the following shell command from within a Node application:

```bash
git grep MySearchString -- 'MyPathToSearchFor'
```

This command runs successfully using's node's `child_process.exec`:

```js
exec("git grep MySearchString -- 'MyPathToSearchFor'") // succeeds!
```

However, I cannot get the command working using `child_process.spawn`, which requires arguments to be provided as an array of strings.

```js
// Spawn works without the pathspec args:
spawn('git', ['grep', 'MySearchString']) // success! exits with code 0

// It fails when the pathspec args are provided:
spawn('git', ['grep', 'MySearchString', '--', "'MyPathToSearchFor'"]) // exits with code 1
spawn('git', ['grep', 'MySearchString', "-- 'MyPathToSearchFor'"]) // exits with code 128
```

How can I provide `spawn` the `-- MyPathToSearchFor` args? How should I translate the dash-dash and pathspec args into spawn parameters?

The problem seems related to quotes in the args, but I'm not sure how to handle those.

Comment: strange, `spawn('git', ['grep', 'MySearchString', '--', 'MyPathToSearchFor'])` should be the correct form

Answer (score 2):

> The problem seems related to quotes in the args, but I'm not sure how to handle those.

Don't include quotes when you use the array argument form, e.g. just

```js
spawn('git', ['grep', 'MySearchString', '--', "MyPathToSearchFor"])
```

With `"'MyPathToSearchFor'"` this makes git look for a file/directory whose name contains a single quote at the start and end (which in theory could exist, but rarely is what you have).